# Mac: Updated HOME environment variable in /etc/launchd.conf and now machine wont boot

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I set the HOME variable in /etc/launchd.conf using the following line: setenv HOME /Users/student

Now the machine wont boot at startup. I tried holding shift at startup but safe mode doesn't seem to be working. I tried holding cmd+s on startup and got into single user mode. I was able to bring up the /etc/launchd.conf file but I can not save/overwrite the existing file due to permission issues.

Is there some way to reset this file from single user mode or other to fix this? I'm open to other approaches as well. I am not a unix/linux power user by any means, fyi :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try booting with cmd+r. This will boot the computer in basically a recovery mode. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you StevenT, is there an option that won't cause me to lose data or anything? There are multiple options that come up.

Comment: I use time machine since I have an external hard drive. If you have an external hard drive and use time machine, it should be able to restore all your files after it reinstalls. You might have to buy the mountain lion DVD. All this is speculative and answered to the best of my ability since I have yet to touch any of those options myself, but I have read a little about it.

Comment: Yeah, this is unfortunately not an option. (This is actually a friend's computer, for simplicity's sake I've referred to it as mine). They haven't run a time machine backup.

I tried running "mount -uw /" in single user mode on my mac and I was able to successfully edit the launchd.conf file, but tried it on my friend's computer and the file is still not editable.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two options, but first a warning: both of these involve using the command line to undo the damage, and if you do it wrong there's a possibility you'll make it even worse. A backup would've been a good idea, but it's a little late for that (well, actually, there are still ways to do it, but they *also* involve a risk of getting it wrong...). So whatever your do, be careful.

Option 1: use single-user mode (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> at startup). This will leave you running as root, which means you are not subject to normal file permissions; after remounting the startup disk for write access (`mount -uw /`) you should not get permissions errors. You said this didn't work; the most likely thing is that you mistyped the command (I see this happen a lot -- people either leave out the "/", or the space between "-uw" and "/"). Hint: if the mount command prints anything (other than the prompt for the next command) you typed it wrong. If that still doesn't do it, check the file's flags and metadata with `ls -leO@ /etc/launchd.conf` and report the results.

Option 2: use recovery mode (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> at startup). This boots from a small hidden partition with a minimal copy of OS X. In recovery mode, pull down the Utilities menu and choose Terminal. This is actually a fair bit like single-user mode, except that the normal startup disk won't be `/`, it'll be `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` (or whatever it's named), and it'll already be mounted for write access. Since there's (probably) a space in the volume name, you'll have to quote or escape it:

```
$ cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"
$ mv launchd.conf launchd.conf-disabled
```